# How to debug dalvikvm rejecting opcode?

Tags: android, dalvik

How do I make sense of these errors?  This is all the log cat releavant to the error. all others are GC  type messages.

```
01-07 19:14:08.536: W/dalvikvm(5780): VFY: register2 v4-5 values 6,24
01-07 19:14:08.536: W/dalvikvm(5780): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0xce at 0x004a
01-07 19:14:08.536: W/dalvikvm(5780): VFY:  rejected Lnz/co/great_ape/headsup/sat_track/SGP4unit_sgp4;.sgp4 (Lnz/co/great_ape/headsup/sat_track/SGP4SatData;D[D[D)Z
01-07 19:14:08.536: W/dalvikvm(5780): Verifier rejected class Lnz/co/great_ape/headsup/sat_track/SGP4unit_sgp4;
```

I know the code, it's about 400 lines of `sgp4 satellite tracking software` (not my code).

The problem is triggered when I create an instance of this class (it's long 400+ lines) and I have tracked the problem down to this section of code by simply commenting out all the code, then un-commenting sections until the error returns,

All the variables here are doubles.  So why is android rejecting this code with opcodes for things like OP_DIV_DOUBLE and OP_DIV_DOUBLE_2ADDR

Any way, here is the section of code.

```
            /* -------------- update for short period periodics ------------ */
            if(satrec.method == 'd')
            {
                cosisq = cosip * cosip;
                satrec.con41 = 3.0 * cosisq - 1.0;
                satrec.x1mth2 = 1.0 - cosisq;
                satrec.x7thm1 = 7.0 * cosisq - 1.0;
            }
            mrt = rl * (1.0 - 1.5 * temp2 * betal * satrec.con41) +
                    0.5 * temp1 * satrec.x1mth2 * cos2u;
            su = su - 0.25 * temp2 * satrec.x7thm1 * sin2u;
            xnode = nodep + 1.5 * temp2 * cosip * sin2u;
            xinc = xincp + 1.5 * temp2 * cosip * sinip * cos2u;
            mvt = rdotl - nm * temp1 * satrec.x1mth2 * sin2u / xke;
            rvdot = rvdotl + nm * temp1 * (satrec.x1mth2 * cos2u +
                    1.5 * satrec.con41) / xke;
```

Comment: If I guess right you call functions which are not supported on your device.

Comment: I searched for the opcode, its OP_DIV_DOUBLE_2ADDR.  The trick is what function is not supported on the device (a nexus phone).  It all looks like common math functions to me.

Comment: Could it be all about the way it's built?

Comment: How about testing this piece of code in a newly created project?

Comment: @full.stack.ex How do you mean about the way it's built?  It builds fine, it's only when being run in android device that dalvikvm rejects this segment of the code. It's not actually doing anything at this point, its only when I create an instance of the class. I do sgp4 = new SGP4(); and thats all.

Comment: In a new android project, blank activity and nothing else, same problem.  Issue is on emulator and on real device.

Comment: FWIW, `register2 v4-5 values 6,24` means that the verifier expected to find a 64-bit value in virtual registers 4 and 5 (each register being 32 bits).  The type of value held in each register is tracked by the verifier; in this case, it should be a `double`, with values 23,24 indicating "double, low part" and "double, high part".  The verifier found a path where the low part held type #6 (a positive byte-sized value from a constant) instead.  This suggests faulty DEX code generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  It seems there was never anything wrong with the code as such, but just the length of the method and the number of variables.  Declaring them outside the method solved the problem.

You can get more info here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/lxiTkNzOvZY